# Can a Boggle use its Dimensional Rift in the mouth of a Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The title almost says it all. Can a Boggle use its Dimensional Rift ability in the mouth of a Bag of Holding (or any sack really), or would a bag not provide a solid enough mouth for them to create their rift?

And if they were able to do so with a bag of holding (example, they snatched one and were running off, the PCs were chasing it and it decided to open the bag dimensional rift to hop in and escape), would that be like putting a portable hole in a bag of holding and open a rift to the astral plane?

Including the ***Dimensional Rift*** text from Volo's P. 128:

> ***Dimensional Rift.*** As a bonus action, the boggle can create an invisible and immobile rift within an opening or frame it can see within 5 feet of it, provided that the space is no bigger than 10 feet on any side. The dimensional rift bridges the distance between that space and any point within 30 feet of it that the boggle can see or specify by distance and direction (such as "30 feet straight up"). While next to the rift, the boggle can see through it and is considered to be next to the destination as well, and anything the boggle puts through the rift (including a portion of its body) emerges at the destination. Only the boggle can use the rift, and it lasts until the end of the boggle's next turn.

And clarifying from the ***Twisting Space*** section of the text. This is what makes me wonder if a sack or bag of holding would even be capable of sustaining the rift:

> ***Twisting Space.*** A boggle can create magical openings to travel short distances or to pilfer items that would otherwise be beyond its
>   reach. To create such a rift in space, a boggle must be adjacent to a
>   space defined by a frame, such as an open window or a doorway, a gap
>   between the bars of a cage, or the opening between the feet or a bed
>   and the floor. The rift is invisible and disappears after a few
>   seconds - enough time for the boggle to step, reach, or attack through
>   it.

It talks about frames, but says nothing specifically about the mouth of a bag. And the examples listed in Volo's all mention more solid frames. I did find this on a site discussing tactics the Boggle uses:

> The catch is that there has to be some kind of “frame” to create the
>   rift in: a window or door, a hole in a wall, a fireplace, an oven
>   door, a ladder, the end of a sawhorse, the underside of a raised bed,
>   the mouth of a basket or amphora, a hollow in a tree, even the body
>   and legs of a Medium or Large animal. Anything will do as long as
>   there’s a solid perimeter around the rift space, no more than 10 feet
>   on a side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two questions there:

- Can the Boogle make the rift open next to a bag of holding?
- Would the rift tear apart the bag of holding sucking everything into the Astral?

---

**Can the Boogle make the rift open next to a bag of holding?**

Yes. But the boogle needs a frame to anchor the opening, no bigger than 10 foot apart.

> To create such a rift in space, a boggle must be adjacent to a space defined by a frame, such as an open window or a doorway, a gap between the bars of a cage, or the opening between the feet of a bed and the floor.

If it desires to move through completely, the frame must be one that would allow the boogle to move through. The mouth of a bag of holding cannot be considered a frame.

The rift **exit** can open right next to the mouth of the bag. No problem in that. But it would still be immovable. The boogle could step into the bag ([but could not get out alone](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69880/can-a-bag-of-holding-be-opened-from-the-inside?rq=1)) or move the bag through the rift.

---

**Would the rift tear apart the bag of holding sucking everything into the Astral?**

No. The rift is just a dimensional opening, not unlike a dimension door spell. it is not an *extradimensional* space. No extra space is created by the rift.