# Can a Boggle put a Tiny creature through its Dimensional Rift?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, creature-size

This is similar to the question [Can a Boggle use its Dimensional Rift in the mouth of a Bag of Holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103739/can-a-boggle-use-its-dimensional-rift-in-the-mouth-of-a-bag-of-holding), which sparked a thought.

---

According to the [boggle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/boggle)'s statblock in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 128):

> ***Dimensional Rift.*** As a bonus action, the boggle can create an
>   invisible and immobile rift within an opening or frame it can see
>   within 5 feet of it, provided that the space is no bigger than 10 feet
>   on any side. The dimensional rift bridges the distance between that
>   space and any point within 30 feet of it that the boggle can see or
>   specify by distance and direction (such as "30 feet straight up").
>   While next to the rift, the boggle can see through it and is
>   considered to be next to the destination as well, and anything the
>   boggle puts through the rift (including a portion of its body) emerges
>   at the destination. **Only the boggle can use the rift**, and it lasts
>   until the end of the boggle's next turn.

We have a [sprite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sprite) traveling with the Boggle in our campaign.  Could the Boggle pass the (Tiny) Sprite through the Rift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's possible, but the boggle needs to be holding it

The language is a bit murky, but this does seem possible. Based on the quote above, the requirements are:

- Rift is contained with an opening or frame the boggle sees within 5' of it
- The opening or frame is no bigger than 10' on any side.
- Can bridge distance up to 30'
- Only the boggle can use it

Therefore, anything the boggle is holding can be moved through the rift as long as it can fit in a 10'x10' space (or smaller if the frame/opening is smaller.)

### Gotta hold the sprite

Because only a boggle can use the rift, in order for the sprite to pass through the rift, the boggle needs to put it in and this suggests it needs to be holding/have control of it. This will be a bit up to your DM, but it wouldn't be unreasonable to require an action to grab the sprite. Whether or not they automatically can grab it or if they have to attempt a grapple will also be up to the DM. However, the Boggle definitely needs to be in control of the sprite in order for it to actively put it through the rift.

Comment: Thanks!  They were thinking of pairing up and breaking into things.