# What effects would casting Enlarge on a bag of holding have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I was watching a video about underrated spells, and one of the spells listed was Enlarge/Reduce. One of the examples given was reducing a large, heavy statue, then the party carrying the statue away, and my mind leaped to "wait, what if you cast Enlarge on a bag of holding?"

My main thoughts are that it would increase its capacity for the duration of the spell, and possibly its weight limit as well, but I'm not too sure

Answer (score 13):

The bag becomes larger. The inner dimensions inside of it remains the same. The entrance of the bag is only connecting it to another plane where the items are stored, the bag itself doesn't lend any reflection of its potential contents.

You can see from the description of the items which say:

> Placing the [haversack/hole] inside an **extradimensional space** created by a Bag of Holding

(emphasis added)

Comment: Seems like a good way to "lock" something inside the bag. Enlarge it and put an object in it too large to come out through the normal size opening. Temporarily make it difficult to pull anything out by casting Reduce on it.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but I feel it should be mentioned that you can fit things in the bag you couldn't before with the opening being wider.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103360/discussion-on-answer-by-somethingsomething-what-effects-would-casting-enlarge-on).

Comment: I went ahead and added some textual support to your answer. Here on this site, supporting answers with evidence is important and greatly improves the quality of the answer. I encourage you to take a look at my edit and further elaborate on it and/or find additional evidence as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Older editions of D&D specifically describe Bags of holding as "always appearing empty", and when you put something into it, it disappears. Based on that, I would say a bag of holding is not an open doorway; it is effectively a permanent teleport spell (or very similar) anchored on the physical bag.  So the question becomes whether magically altering the dimensions of the bag messes with the teleport enchantment.

Specific to your question: I would *not* expect enlarging the bag to alter its holding capacity in any way.  The bag is connected to an extradimensional space.  At best you're making the opening bigger; but that wouldn't in any way alter that "interior".  Think of it like a TARDIS from Doctor Who -- the external "real world interface" can be any size and shape, and at best you're merely altering the doorway itself. The interior doesn't change.  (That said, a TARDIS doorway *is* an open portal, not a teleport; I'm just observing the clear distinction between interior and exterior.)

It's really a DM judgement call as to whether casting a spell that radically alters the real world object to which the enchantment is anchored damages the enchantment itself.  Personally, I would decide a percentage chance, and roll to see if they still have a bag of holding, or if the enchantment is broken and they are left with an ordinary bag.

Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114723/14729

Also related: There was an early story line in Knights of the Dinner Table relating specifically to the workings of a bag of holding. Worth reading, and pretty entertaining, if this topic interests you.... https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12216585-knights-of-the-dinner-table

Comment: Oh, no, the opening of the bag most definitely qualifies as a portal.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Are you sure about that? https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114708/14729

Comment: Both of the top answers in the question you linked describe the opening as a portal. I'm not sure what you're getting at?

Comment: The #2 answer on that question is *mine* and I certainly know what I said. Both answers openly ponder whether it's an opening, like a hole, or teleportation. The point that the bag itself looks empty and putting something in it causes it to disappear strongly suggests that it is *not* just an opening such as a hole. Don't get so hung up on the word, and look at the meaning of what you're reading

Comment: You should notice that the description for the 5e version of the *Bag of Holding* distinctly *lacks* the *always appears to be empty* portion of the description. With this taken into consideration, it can easily be surmised that it indeed, has an open portal to an extradimensional space.